# How to insert line breaks between List Items

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a HTML form, and I'm using UL's and LI's to organize my fields. 
Inside each LI i have a label and a Input. After some CSS to make LI display:inline-block, I get this result:

[image]

I have the example in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/cygv07px/

The question is that I want that the street field to be in a new line, like this:

[image]

I achievied that by putting a `<br />` element between the `<LI>`, but that doesn't seems to be a elegant solution, and I keep getting validation messages from Visual Studio, saying that I cant have a BR element inside a LI.

How can i specify a line break before Street Field (or after the name field) in a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `float:left` and **clear** it for every odd child.

```
li { 
 list-style: none; 
 float: left;
}
label { display: block }

li:nth-child(odd) { clear: left;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
     li { 
       list-style: none; 
       float: left;
     }
     label { display: block }

     li:nth-child(odd) { clear: left; }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
   <ul>
    <li>
      <label for="docNo">Doc Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="docNo" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="street">Street</label>
      <input type="text" id="street" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <label for="houseNumber">House Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="houseNumber" />
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Damn, you were faster :D

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use display block and floats.

```css
li { 
  list-style: none; 
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: left;
}

label { display: block }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <label for="docNo">Doc Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="docNo" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="street">Street</label>
    <input type="text" id="street" />
  </li>
  <li>
    <label for="houseNumber">House Number</label>
    <input type="text" id="houseNumber" />
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

At some point I read that one should avoid float whenever possible as it breaks alot of other things you can potentially do with that element.

I think a flex-box based solution might be better.

*Note that the container is not needed. I just used it to simulate the list having some finite space on the page.*

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
ul {
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: wrap;
}
li {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0; 
  padding: 0;
  width: 50%;
}

.container {
  width: 25rem;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">   
    <ul>
        <li>
          <label for="docNo">Doc Number</label>
          <input type="text" id="docNo" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" id="name" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="street">Street</label>
          <input type="text" id="street" />
        </li>
        <li>
          <label for="houseNumber">House Number</label>
          <input type="text" id="houseNumber" />
        </li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a slightly different solution. When you use an HTML `<table>` element, you don't even need any CSS to format it. It also avoids `float` which in my experience can cause issues. My code is below or at https://jsfiddle.net/9myL5rbk/.

```css
label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="docNo">Doc Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="docNo" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label for="street">Street</label>
      <input type="text" id="street" />
    </td>
    <td>
      <label for="houseNumber">House Number</label>
      <input type="text" id="houseNumber" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

the previous solutions didn't work for me as I had some classes already set in my framework and I got weird resoluts, so I got a ver easy and simple solution!

If you have and ul displayed horizontaly and want to get a br: just add an extra 'empty' li with a 100% width, so it won't be displayed but it will produce a break line!

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>your li element  </li>
  <li>your li element  </li>
  <li style="width: 100%;"></li>
  <li>your li element  </li>
  <li>your li element  </li>
</ul>
```